# Disable Haptic Touch on IOS 13 (keeping 3D Touch)

Tags: iphone, multi-touch, ios, haptic-feedback

I recently upgraded my iPhone 6s+ to iOS13.

Haptic Touch is getting in the way of how I use the phone.  It's slower than 3D Touch, pops up and distracts me when my finger rests on the screen and provides no functionality I didn't already have.

Is the only way to get rid of Haptic Touch to restore from backup to iOS12?

Am I missing something about Haptic Touch?  It seemed like a UI hack to allow 3D Touch features on budget iPhones, but for some reason was forced on everything?

**For those searching on this:**

"3D Touch" is used by pressing hard on the screen, e.g., in text areas, you can press hard on the keyboard and move a cursor around, pressing hard again to select words, sentences or dragging out a precise selection with only your thumb.

"Haptic Touch" is used by resting your finger on the screen and waiting until there's a vibration.  E.g., the keyboard cursor can be activated by resting your thumb on the space bar then dragged around the text.  You select by touching the screen with a second finger (without removing your first finger from the screen... you'll need two hands) then dragging one of your fingers to expand the selection.

---

Update: Tried 13.2, it's still not possible to disable only Haptic Touch in the settings menu.

I've submitted a feature request here, if you're in the same boat, please do the same: https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: I realize that this is something you'd really like to see, but 3D Touch is dead. Yes, I understand that there are some pieces of hardware out there which still support it, but the _feature_ was only ever supported on some iPhones, and none of the new iPhones support it. The idea that Apple is now going to _add_ an option for people with that older hardware (which may not even be supported by the next version of iOS at all) is so far beyond "never going to happen" that I'm not sure I can adequately describe it. You might as well try to shovel the beach back into the ocean.

Comment: It would be nice to have an option to disable only HAPTIC TOUCH and leave 3D TOUCH, since 3D TOUCH does the same and more, and HAPTIC TOUCH only interfereS with it.

Answer (score 2):

Apple discontinued 3D Touch in iOS devices starting with iOS 13.  3D Touch relied on special screen hardware to determine the amount of pressure being applied.  Newer iPhones (anything after the iPhone XS and its variants)  do not have that type of screen.

The only way to return to 3D Touch on older devices with pressure-sensitive screens is to revert back to an older iOS version.

There's no way turn off Haptic Touch on iOS 13 (the latest iOS version as of now).  You can adjust the sensitivity and duration by going to `Settings -> Accessibility -> Touch -> 3D & Haptic Touch`.  You can turn 3D Touch on and off here.

[image]

From here you can adjust the "Touch Duration" to see if that helps you.

Comment: 3D touch works fine on iOS 13 with supported devices.  To me, from what I've read so far, Haptic touch interferes with 3D touch and cannot be turned off.   Turning off 3D touch is missing the point.  Haptic touch is a downgrade.

Comment: Yes, like I mentioned in the answer, 3D Touch will work on older devices, that have the supported hardware (I noticed I could've worded that better) and there's no way to disable Haptic Touch.  I included the settings for 3D Touch in case that helps you or someone else with a similar problem/question.

Comment: The question wasn't about how to enable 3D touch.  It's enabled by default on devices which support it.  The key part of your answer "The only way to return to 3D Touch ... is to revert back to an older iOS version" is wrong... but that wasn't the question.  You do add that "no there's no way to disable Haptic Touch" , but I don't think you have experience with this feature.

Comment: Your question was "Is the only way to get rid of this to restore from backup to IOS12?".  I answered that question.  I also supplied steps if you, or anyone else, wants to adjust the settings for 3D Touch.  I've developed dozens of apps that use Haptic Touch and used almost every iPhone since 3GS so I'm very familiar with the feature.  If this doesn't answer your question then hopefully someone else will provide an answer that better addresses your concerns.

Comment: Haptic touch is the future. 3D Touch is dead. Sorry if you don't like the answer, but that's the answer. No, there is no way around it other than what @fsb has told you already.

Comment: @TJLuoma 3D Touch is not dead on my device, it works perfectly.  As per the **question**... Haptic Touch is the problem.

Comment: What @TJLuoma means is that Apple is no longer developing that feature and they have advised developers not to use it.  3D Touch and Haptic Feedback are similar but different features because they do different things.